# Doubts about some sentences - は usage in combination with other particles

Tags: particle-は

I'm studying for JLPT4 and i'm trying to understand the questions on the test sample of the official page.

My doubts(bold words are the correct answer, i've checked it in the answers document):

- 誕生日に　田中さんから　何を　もらったんですか。
- 田中さん　**からは**　腕時計を　もらいました。

The listed answers are: からが　からに　からで　からは. 
Why is the answer からは and not just から?

next:

- すみません、山田さんは　どこですか？
- 山田さんは　会議中ですが、会議は　１１時半　**までには**　終わると　思います。

Answers: までは　までには　までも　までにも

Why is it までにも and no までには? I can understand までに but i can't understand the last は.

That's all, thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct answer for the second question is 11時半**までには**. Please [double-check for yourself](http://www.jlpt.jp/samples/sample12.html).

Comment: you're right. But why は after までに?

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Comment: Actually is just one question. The question is why there is は where it should not be, there is no reason for it according of what i've studied.

Comment: @KaiKanbara The は usage is perfectly normal to me. Could you explain where you think it's weird according to what you've learned?

Comment: All the examples i've seen were から without は. I've studied "japanese in mangaland", "Genki" and searched  for から grammar on Google.

Answer (score 1):

「からは」、「までには」がそれぞれ正解です。

まず、問題作成者の意図を汲んで解答すると良いのではないでしょうか。
おそらく、単独の「に」と、結合した「には」のニュアンスの差を理解させたい問題なのでしょう。

「に」と「は」が結合した「には」の場合は「取り立て」、「注目」、「抽出」、「特記」、「限定」のニュアンスが含まれます。
「田中さん　からは　腕時計を　もらいました。」という言い方をした場合、他の誰かからもプレゼントを貰っていることが暗黙に前提されています。
複数の人の中で、「《特にorとりわけ》田中さんからについて《限定or抽出or注目or取り立て》すると…」というニュアンスです。

「には」という表現は、「限定」のニュアンスが加わるので、秘密の話、内緒話の場面でよく使われます。
例文：「あなたには打ち明けておくけれども…」を「あなたに打ち明けておくけれども…」とは言いません。
例文：「彼には黙っていて欲しい。」を「「彼に黙っていて欲しい。」とは言いません。

「までには」と言った場合、「『まだ終わらないのか！』と怒っている相手をなだめようとして、話者が申し訳なく思っている気持ち」や「話者の個人的で希望的な観測（おそらく終わるだろう）」という気持ちの強調（特記）が追加されます。

単に「までに」と言った場合は客観的な表現に留まり、話者の特別な感情は付加されません。

文法面の表面上は、「までには」という表現で特定の時刻に「注目or限定」する形式を採用しています。
しかし、実際には、話者が相手に許しを請う感情の表現を「取り立て」、「注目」、「抽出」、「特記」という意味が込められています。

Comment: This looks like good content.  Considering that the questioner is studying for JLPT level 4, I doubt they can read your answer as-is.  Would you consider adding a translation?